# Missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' AND no atribute length

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm doing a stupid 'anticoronavirus' for PC. 
This is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import random
window=Tk()
window.geometry('500x500')
window.resizable(False, False)
window.title('Anti Corona')
window.config(bg='light blue')
anti=tk.Label(text='Anti Corona')
anti.config(bg='light blue', font=('Arial black', 50))
anti.pack()
anti2=tk.Label(text='')
anti2.config(bg='light blue', font=('Arial black', 100))
anti2.pack()
def scaner(self):
    self.f1=tk.Frame()
    self.f1.pack()
    self.progress=ttk.Progressbar(f1)
    self.progress.length(50)
    self.progress.pack() 
scan=tk.Button(window, text='Scan!')
scan.config(height=1, width=10, font=('Century gothic', 30, 'bold'), bg='green', disabledforeground='', command=scaner())
scan.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

The problem is it outputs an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cicle.EAAULAINF1W-008\Desktop\Anticorona.py", line 23, in <module>
    scan.config(height=1, width=10, font=('Century gothic', 30, 'bold'), bg='green', disabledforeground='', command=scaner())
TypeError: scaner() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

But when I quit all the `self` in the def, the output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cicle.EAAULAINF1W-008\Desktop\Anticorona.py", line 23, in <module>
    scan.config(height=1, width=10, font=('Century gothic', 30, 'bold'), bg='green', disabledforeground='', command=scaner())
  File "C:\Users\cicle.EAAULAINF1W-008\Desktop\Anticorona.py", line 20, in scaner
    progress.length(50)
AttributeError: 'Progressbar' object has no attribute 'length'
```

I don't know what to do! Help me, please!

Comment: You are using self in a non class function. Also `command=scaner()` is not correct. you want to do `command=scaner` instead. delete `self from `scanner()`.

Comment: `progress.length()` is not valid either. You should do `ttk.Progressbar(f1, length=50)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems here.

1st your `command=scaner()` needs to be `command=scaner`.

2nd your function should not take `self` as an argument. This is not built in a class.

3rd `progress.length(50)` will cause an error as well as there is no such method called `length` in the progress class. Instead you want to do `Progressbar(f1, length=50)`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def scanner():
    global progress
    f1 = tk.Frame()
    f1.pack()
    progress = ttk.Progressbar(f1, length=50)
    progress.pack()


window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('500x500')
window.resizable(False, False)
window.title('Anti Corona')
window.config(bg='light blue')

tk.Label(text='Anti Corona', bg='light blue', font=('Arial black', 50)).pack()
tk.Label(text='', bg='light blue', font=('Arial black', 100)).pack()
tk.Button(window, text='Scan!', bg='green', disabledforeground='', height=1, width=10, 
          font=('Century gothic', 30, 'bold'), command=scanner).pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, but the bar now is always on screen. What I want is that the progressbar appears when I click the button

Comment: @ArionSintesSintes well if that is happening then my guess is you didn't update the command field. Because that was the 1st issue I listed and if you do not update that then the bar will pop up the instant the program runs. That or you have something else in your code calling `scanner()`.

Comment: I don't know what do you mean with update the command field. (Sorry, my english is bad)

Comment: Cammand must be `comman=scanner` and not `command=scanner()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your method signature is incorrect.

```
def scanner(self):
    pass
```

You should only have `self` if the method is a class instance member, ie.

```
class Hello:
    def print_it(self, msg):
        print(msg)
```

and you would call it via the class

```
Hello().print_it('world')
```

however since you created a function outside of a class the `self` is unnecessary.  Updating your method signature to remove the `self` will fix that problem, ie:

```
def scanner():
    pass
```